# How to pass interviews if you never contributed to an open source project?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, code

I am getting stuck already in few interviews when the companies ask me to show them my source code.

During 10 years of career all "my" source code is private, sealed by many NDAs source code that is nearly impossible I can show them.

Because I was so devoted at my professional work, I never had time to devote to any open source project. So no I did not contribute to any source project.

Is there any immediate solution? i.e. I know I could start creating an open source project, or contribute to an existing one, etc. But I see the effort of doing this as grounding a new company. So it is not happening immediately.

Comment: Do they really require having contributed to open source code or is that just one question among others? They can't seriously assume everyone has. Most programmers haven't, for a simple reason: they need to earn money with coding and that is pretty hard to achieve with open source code. You could ask them if company's open source code is available to present to the next employer :-)

Comment: They don't need to be big OS projects. Just a couple of PoCs should be more than enough. Eg. a simple CRUD project, some simple serverless thing, an example hardware 2x16 print, or a string parse thing like "which word appears the most in the input file" kind of thing. Something that takes an hour or two to create.

Answer (score 7):

I've never contributed to a project where the source code is publicly available, and I've been fairly continuously employed for a lot longer than ten years. Open source projects are not essential to being hired, at least not by companies that know how to do professional development.

If you are asked for source code I suggest saying that all your projects have been critical to your employers, and that's why you can't show source code. And that your employers have always kept you busy enough you haven't had time for side projects.

Comment: Thank you guys. Almost all your answers guys look correct to me. I agree with you guys. The point here is that the reallity is different. I have been turned down already in two applications because not having a "github repo".

Comment: Did they actually say that they turned you down because you didn't have a "Github repo" or are you assuming that?

Comment: Yes, that is my concern.

Comment: In that case I would create a github repo and put some example code on it, it sounds like it's not going to hurt your chances. It sounds like it doesn't have to be a big project shared by thousands, they just want some tangible examples of your code quality which they can look at.

Answer (score 2):

With 10 years of experience you should have a pretty good professional network you can use for character and quality of work references. If you have former project managers and bosses willing to be those references then that would be a great start.

Another immediate solution is to offer to do a coding challenge meeting the criteria they lay out. This is actually pretty common, and not just for developer positions.